# Passing 2D array to a Function: zero-value and print issue

Tags: c, arrays

I want to pass 2D array to a function. I've written 3 functions:

- make all the values == 0;
- implement it with desired values;
- print matrix;

My output looks wrong. I checked in debug mod that mapZero works right (it implements zeros by all rows and columns but). The first matrix must consist of only zero values, the second one with implemented (btw, why my commented code in mapInit can't be built? It seems I did it right). and the third matrix is a new matrix implemented with my algorithm (I'm writin wave-algorithm to find the shortest way to a final point).

I can't get how and where I should use pointers (maybe the problem is in it?) and how to pass WIDTH and HEIGHT with a right way.

[image]

```
int mapZero(int * map[WIDTH][WIDTH])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j)
        {
            map[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int mapPrint(int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j)
        {
            printf("%2d  ", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int mapInit(int * map[WIDTH][WIDTH])
{
    /*
    map[WIDTH][WIDTH] =
    {
        { 127,1,1,1,1,1,1,  1 },
        { 0,  1,0,0,0,1,1,  1 },
        { 1,  1,1,1,0,0,0,  1 },
        { 1,  0,0,1,0,0,0,  1 },
        { 1,  0,1,1,0,0,1,  1 },
        { 1,  1,1,1,1,1,1,  1 },
        { 0,  1,0,0,1,0,1,  1 },
        { 1,  1,1,1,1,1,1,255 },
    };
    */

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j)
        {
            map[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j)
    {
        map[0][j] = 1;
        map[7][j] = 1;
        map[j][7] = 1;
        map[5][j] = 1;
    }

    for (int j = 2; j < 5; ++j)
    {
        map[j][0] = 1;
    }

    map[1][1] = 1; map[1][5] = 1; map[1][6] = 1;
    map[2][1] = 1; map[2][2] = 1; map[2][3] = 1;
    map[3][3] = 1;
    map[4][2] = 1; map[4][3] = 1; map[4][6] = 1;
    map[6][1] = 1; map[6][4] = 1; map[6][6] = 1; map[6][7] = 1;
    map[0][0] = 22;
    map[7][7] = 99;

    return 0;
}
```

My main.c:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDTH 8
#define HEIGHT 8

int mapZero(int * map[WIDTH][WIDTH]);
int mapPrint(int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT]);
int mapInit(int * map[WIDTH][WIDTH]);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    short int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    short int visited[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

    mapZero(visited);
    mapZero(map);
    mapInit(map, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    printf("Matrix of zeroed-visited cells:\n\n");
    mapPrint(visited, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    printf("Matrix of the map:\n\n");
    mapPrint(map, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you ignore compiler warnings? You are required to enable the recommended warnings and fix them before asking about debugging problems. And read [ask].

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument declaration `int * map[WIDTH][WIDTH]` is equal to `int * (*map)[WIDTH]`. That's an array of array of *pointers* to `int`. You pass an array of array of `short int`.

Drop the asterisk, use the correct type in the arguments, and the correct symbolic constant: `short int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT]`.

You also call `mapInit` and `mapPrint` with two extra arguments that are not in the declared functions.

The compiler should have complained about *all* of this.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't take a notice how I've declared the arrays in main(). Now it's correct.

But I'm still interested why I can't implement my array with the way It's shown in comments in mapInit()

Comment: @GeorgeZ. Because that's just not a valid syntax in C. Generally you can not *assign* to an array, just initialize it, assign to individual elements, or copy to it. With the second alternative, you can create an initialized array like you want in the `mapInit` function, and then [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) from that to `map`.

Answer (score 1):

`int * map[WIDTH][WIDTH]` is an array of pointers. It is not compatible with the array in the caller so the code should not compile. Change this to `int map[WIDTH][WIDTH]`.

Similarly, an array of `short` is not necessarily compatible with an array of `int`. Use the same type everywhere.

If your code compiled without errors/warnings there's something very wrong with your compiler.

By the rule of array parameter adjustment ("decay"), the above array declaration, when part of a parameter list, will get adjusted by the compiler to the pointer to the first element. The first element of the 2D array is a 1D array, so it gets adjusted to an array pointer to a 1D array, `int (*)[WIDTH]`.